# creating a table view in the UIView controller class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hii every one

how can i design the following screen, inside UIViewController class (not table view controller) programatically

[image]

thanx in advance

Comment: have you declared and set delegates? in .h and .m files?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `UITableView` inside the view of the View controller and set the data source and `delegate` of the table view as the view controller. Make the `UITableView` a grouped one..

This [tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/20/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-3-grouped-uitableview/) will help you

If you want to a new table view initialize it using

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;
```

You can do the following:

```
UITableView *myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Comment: thnax for ur reply, can u give me some sample code,i need to create that code programatically

Comment: Hi, TableView style property was readonly.SO how can set from the code (with out using IB)

Comment: Initialize the table with the style like `tableViewContoller = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
`

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code;

```
myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
myTableView.delegate = self;
myTableView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:myTableView];
```

Comment: TableView style property is readonly know so i am getting error at this line myTableView.style=UITableViewStyleGrouped; error is assigning property with readonly attribute is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the tutorial -

[UITableView grouped table tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/)

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in .h

```
@interface yourViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

{

      UITableView *yourTable;

}
```

and add following code in .m inside viewDidLoad

```
 yourTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 300, 300)];  
  yourTable.dataSource = self;  
  yourTable.style=UITableViewStyleGrouped;  
  [self.view addSubview:yourTable];
```

and also you will have to set datasource and delegates as per your requirement

Comment: what property should i set,,i am getting following error at line yourTable.style=UITableViewStyleGrouped;  object cannot be set either its readonly or no setter found i have tried readWrite,copy  but still i am getting same error

Comment: okay..1) are you using the viewController right?? then dont do anything on IB ..open a viewcontroller paste the code which is written here..and then set num of section and num of rows and cellForRowAtIndexPath delegates... have you done this ? its better if you paste some code

Comment: do this ...simply...`@property(nonatomic, retain)UITableView *yourTable;` and in .m file `@synthesize yourTable`

Comment: do you want to implement it programatically or using IB?